# string into a list in Python

Tags: python, string, list

I have a str  that contains a list of numbers and I want to convert it to a list. Right now I can only get the entire list in the 0th entry of the list, but I want each number to be an element of a list. Does anyone know of an easy way to do this in Python?

```
for i in in_data.splitlines():
    print i.split('Counter32: ')[1].strip().split()
```

my result not i want

```
['12576810']\n['1917472404']\n['3104185795']
```

my data

```
IF-MIB::ifInOctets.1 = Counter32: 12576810
IF-MIB::ifInOctets.2 = Counter32: 1917472404
IF-MIB::ifInOctets.3 = Counter32: 3104185795
```

i want result

```
['12576810','1917472404','3104185795']
```

Comment: how does your initial string look like?

Comment: It depends on the layout of the string. if it's just `"4 8 15 16 23 42"`, then making it into a list is easy. If there's a lot of extra junk in the string, then it is harder.

Answer (score 8):

Given your data as

```
>>> data="""IF-MIB::ifInOctets.1 = Counter32: 12576810
IF-MIB::ifInOctets.2 = Counter32: 1917472404
IF-MIB::ifInOctets.3 = Counter32: 3104185795"""
```

You can use regex where the intent is more clear

```
>>> import re
>>> [re.findall("\d+$",e)[0] for e in data.splitlines()]
['12576810', '1917472404', '3104185795']
```

or as @jamylak as pointed out

```
re.findall("\d+$",data,re.MULTILINE)
```

Or [str.rsplit](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit) which will have a edge on performance

```
>>> [e.rsplit()[-1] for e in data.splitlines()]
['12576810', '1917472404', '3104185795']
```

Comment: Instead of using `data.splitlines()` for the `regex` version you can do. `re.findall("\d+$",data,re.MULTILINE)`

Comment: @jamylak: Aha nice, I forgot. THanks

Comment: data Each line have '\n', Your answer is not I ultimately want.

Answer (score 5):

You are already quite far. Based on the code you have, try this:

```
result = []
for i in in_data.splitlines():
    result.append(i.split('Counter32: ')[1].strip())
print result
```

you could also do:

```
result = [i.split('Counter32: ')[1].strip() for i in in_data.splitlines()]
```

Then, you can also go and look at what @Abhijit and @KurzedMetal are doing with regular expressions. In general, that would be the way to go, but I really like how you avoided them with a simple split.

Comment: Unmatched parentheses in line 3.

Answer (score 2):

My best try with the info you gave:

```
>>> data = r"['12576810']\n['1917472404']\n['3104185795']"
>>> import re
>>> re.findall("\d+", data)
['12576810', '1917472404', '3104185795']
```

you could even convert it to int or long if necesary with `map()`

```
>>> map(int, re.findall("\d+", data))
[12576810, 1917472404, 3104185795L]
>>> map(long, re.findall("\d+", data))
[12576810L, 1917472404L, 3104185795L]
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how I'd do it.

```
data="""IF-MIB::ifInOctets.1 = Counter32: 12576810 ... IF-MIB::ifInOctets.2 = Counter32: 1917472404 ... IF-MIB::ifInOctets.3
= Counter32: 3104185795"""

[ x.split()[-1] for x in data.split("\n") ]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
with open('in.txt') as f:
 numbers=[y.split()[-1] for y in f]
print(numbers)      

  ['12576810', '1917472404', '3104185795']
```

**or:**

```
with open('in.txt') as f:
    numbers=[]
    for x in f:
        x=x.split()
        numbers.append(x[-1])
print(numbers)  

['12576810', '1917472404', '3104185795']
```

Comment: .split() removes whitespace at the start and end of string. The .rstrip() call is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

```
result = [(item[(item.rfind(' ')):]).strip() for item in list_of_data]
```

A variant using list comprehension. Iterator over all line of data, find the last index of a blank, cut down the strip from last found blank position to it's end, strip the resulting string (erase possible blanks) and put the result in a new list.

```
    data = """F-MIB::ifInOctets.1 = Counter32: 12576810
IF-MIB::ifInOctets.2 = Counter32: 1917472404
IF-MIB::ifInOctets.3 = Counter32: 3104185795"""
    result = [ (item[(item.rfind(' ')):]).strip() for item in data.splitlines()]
    print result
```

Result:

```
['12576810', '1917472404', '3104185795']
```

Comment: in_error,in_data = commands.getstatusoutput(in_cmd)

if in_error != 0:
    print "Critical - cmd is error!! pls check!!!"
else:
    for e in in_data.splitlines():
        print e.rsplit()[-1]

Comment: I didn't specify the input and wrote 'list_of_data' instead, that's right. It's not the best solution, I see that now, but it's short and works.